# Keep null values last in nhibernate sorting

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate

I have to keep null values always last in sorting, irrespect of sorting order(asc or desc).

I used code something like this.

```
criteria
   .AddOrder(Order.Desc(
          Projections.Cast(
                 NHibernateUtil.Decimal, 
                 Projections.Property("col1"))));

criteria
     .AddOrder(Order.Asc(
           Projections.Cast(
                 NHibernateUtil.Decimal, 
                 Projections.Property("col1"))));
```

i have read this link :

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/control-null-data-in-oracle-using-the-order-by-clause/121

## UPDATE

In this link you can see **nulls last** for sorting. how can i implement this in nhibernate in above code?
any help?

Answer (score 1):

We can use standard SQL Function `COALESCE` and use it as a projection for `ORDER BY`

```
using NHibernate.Dialect.Function;
using NHibernate.Criterion;
...

// sql function definition
var sqlFunction = new SQLFunctionTemplate(NHibernateUtil.String
                                         , "COALESCE(Col1, 'zzzz')");
// create projection
var projection = Projections.SqlFunction(sqlFunction, NHibernateUtil.String);

// order by projection
criteria.AddOrder(new Order(projection, false));
```

And it depends on your needs how will be `NULL` substituted ('zzzzz' or '000' or ..) to move it at the end or at the beginning. So if the order is ascending projection will use high chars if descending low chars. While there is some overhead, it will do that job

Comment: actually by doing this, i need not worry about null values while sorting. Null values should always come last. hope u understand my point. will this happen if i follow your answer?

Comment: If I do understand you correctly, you have to (following my answer) do some `if` statement. If the *Order by* should be `ASC` then to put null down we have to convert them to some high values (e.g. char 'Z' or for decimal to '999999'). in case of `DESC` it must be replaced with some low values. On the other hand, that will work on any DB engine.